# Order of answers with the same score (usually zero)

Tags: support, answers

I wonder what influences the order of answers that has the same score. It mostly happens when two users post answers moreorless simultaneously.

Comment: I don't have a reference, but I thought it was random for answers with the same score, unless of course one of them is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The order of answers with the same number of votes is random and will change every time you load the page. The accepted answer however is always on top, except if it is a self-accepted answer, where the accept flag is ignored for the order.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know the detail about self-accepted answers.

Comment: This assumes of course (?) that one has the answers ordered by votes, I suppose. I have them ordered by activity  most of the time…